# Return default value as integer from SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql

I've a select statement such as which returns the row as int,

I've an if else wherein if no row is found i return -1 as a row.

now, if the row is found, the value is returned in int, where as when no row is found its returned in long.

I've converted the returned value to DataRow in C#

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM STS st WHERE st.plugin_id = plugin_id)
    THEN
    SELECT id FROM STS st WHERE st.plugin_id= plugin_id AND st.channel_id = channel_id LIMIT 1;
    ELSE 
      SELECT -1 int(50) AS "id";
    end IF;
END
```

In the IF statement the value for the row "id" is of type int, where is the value of "id" in the else statement is of type long. basically i need to typecast.

Comment: Sure you're using SQL Server?   `LIMIT` is for MySQL, I'm pretty sure.   Anyway, what is your question?

Comment: @TabAlleman you're right, Thanks for pointing out. I've just removed it

Comment: Thoughts:  
1. You're using C#... this may not be a SQL issue but schema expecting (and converting along the way to) a long.  
2. Are you using ADO(.Net), EF?  
3. That int(50) sets a display width of 50 characters.  Your data adapter may be interpreting and using the biggest int type it knows.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to solve this issue,

## 1.

Declare value as default with data type.

```
DECLARE DefaultResponse INT DEFAULT -1;
```

## 2.

Cast into UNSIGNED.

```
SELECT CAST(-1 AS UNSIGNED)
```